# Set listview rows visibility by its content

Tags: android, json, listview, separator, simpleadapter

I am an amateur Andriod programmer and my app shows a JSON string into a  listview. This is the JSON object:

```
    {"datos":[{"TITULO":"PRUEBA1","NOMBRELINEA":"CORTE CABALLERO","MONTO":"12.84"},
    {"TITULO":"PRUEBA1","NOMBRELINEA":"SECADO","MONTO":"8.56"},
    {"TITULO":"PRUEBA1","NOMBRELINEA":"PEINADO CABALLERO","MONTO":"0"},
    {"TITULO":"PRUEBA2","NOMBRELINEA":"LAVADO KERAS","MONTO":"7.49"},
    {"TITULO":"PRUEBA2","NOMBRELINEA":"MASCARA KERAS","MONTO":"10.70"},
    {"TITULO":"PRUEBA3","NOMBRELINEA":"MECHAS CORTO","MONTO":"6.42"},
    {"TITULO":"PRUEBA3","NOMBRELINEA":"MECHAS LARGO","MONTO":"10"}]}
```

I managed to put the JSON into the listview using a simple adapter and a JSON parser and the result can be seen on this image:

http://imgur.com/cnlBlpm

However, i want it to look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNjvr.jpg

I like Cyril Mottier's suggestion about using the visibility property of the View class and setting the rows GONE when repeated, but the code that he suggests is for static data:

This is the code for the JSON Parser:

```
    public class JSONParser {
    /** Recibe un JSONobject y retorna una lista */
    public List<HashMap<String,String>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

    JSONArray jDatos = null;
    try {
        /** Recupera todos los elementos en el arreglo 'datos' */
        jDatos = jObject.getJSONArray("datos");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /** Invoking getCountries with the array of json object
    * where each json object represent a country
    */
    return getDatos(jDatos);
    }

    private List<HashMap<String, String>> getDatos(JSONArray jDatos){
    int datoCount = jDatos.length();
    List<HashMap<String, String>> datoList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> dato = null;

    /** Taking each country, parses and adds to list object */
    for(int i=0; i<datoCount;i++){
        try {
            /** Call getCountry with country JSON object to parse the country */
            dato = getDato((JSONObject)jDatos.get(i));
            datoList.add(dato);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return datoList;
    }

    /** Parsing the JSON object */
    private HashMap<String, String> getDato(JSONObject jDato){

    HashMap<String, String> dato = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String nombre = "";
    String precio="";
    String tipo="";

    try {
        tipo = jDato.getString("TITULO");
        nombre = jDato.getString("NOMBRELINEA");
        precio = jDato.getString("MONTO");

        dato.put("TITULO", tipo);
        dato.put("NOMBRELINEA", nombre);
        dato.put("MONTO", precio);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dato;
    }
    }
```

And this is the main activity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.l1);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new 
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
}
private String xHttpPost(String targetURL, String Variable, String Valor){
    String urlParameters = "";
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;  
    try {
        //Crear parametros del post
        urlParameters = Variable + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Valor, "UTF-8");
        //Crear conexion            
        url = new URL(targetURL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");  

        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        //Send request
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream   (connection.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes (urlParameters);
        wr.flush ();
        wr.close ();

        //Get Response  
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        rd.close();

        connection.disconnect();
        return sb.toString();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        return e.toString();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        return e.toString();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        return e.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        return e.toString(); 
    }
}

public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    String Consulta = "SELECT lt.nombre AS titulo, LC.nombrecombo AS NombreLinea,(Select Sum(Precioventa1) as Precio from productos where Codigo in (Select                 IdProducto from listacombodetalle LCD where LCD.idcombo = Lc.Id)) as Monto FROM   LISTATITULO LT, LISTACOMBO LC where  Lt.id = Lc.idtitulo";
    String Z = xHttpPost("http://192.168.1.2/android/api/ConsultarFbLP", "query", Consulta);
    String Q = "{" + " \"datos\":" + Z + "}";
    Toast.makeText(this, Q, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ListViewLoaderTask listViewLoaderTask = new ListViewLoaderTask();
    listViewLoaderTask.execute(Q);
}
public class ListViewLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, SimpleAdapter>{

    JSONObject jObject;
    /** Doing the parsing of xml data in a non-ui thread */
    @Override 
    protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... Q) {
        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(Q[0]);
            JSONParser JsonParser = new JSONParser();
            JsonParser.parse(jObject);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("JSON Exception1",e.toString());
        }

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        List<HashMap<String, String>> datos = null;

        try{
            /** Getting the parsed data as a List construct */
            datos = jsonParser.parse(jObject);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
        }

        /** Keys used in Hashmap */
        String[] from = {"TITULO","NOMBRELINEA","MONTO"};

        /** Ids of views in listview_layout */
        int[] to = {R.id.textViewT,R.id.textViewR,R.id.textViewP};
        /** Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        *  R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
        */
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), datos, R.layout.lv_item, from, to);

        return adapter;

    }

    /** Invoked by the Android system on "doInBackground" is executed completely */
    /** This will be executed in ui thread */
     @Override 
     protected void onPostExecute(SimpleAdapter adapter) {

        /** Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file */
        ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.lv_datos);

        /** Setting the adapter containing the country list to listview */
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


}
}
```

This is the XML who fill the listview

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewT"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_weight=".6"
    android:background="#f00"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="Tipo de servicio"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="60sp" 
    android:visibility="visible"/>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewR"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewT"
    android:text="Renglon"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="40sp" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewP"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textViewR"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewR"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewR"
    android:background="#BABABF"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Precio"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="40sp" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Any suggestion on how to hide the repeated rows? And sorry about the links, im new.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should create your own custom adapter, inheriting from BaseAdapter, or ArrayAdapter, maybe even SimpleAdapter. Them you will have to override some methods, including getView. There before returning the view, you can set the visibility to GONE or VISIBLE. That should work.

Comment: Well, in the code above i got a custom simpleadapter, but i dont know exactly how to implement getView to tell the code what rows should be set GONE, if you can help me explaining to me where and how to do it that'll be great. I dont want to sound lazy but i've been stuck on this 2 weeks

Comment: No, you're instantiating the SimpleAdapter class, but not implementing a custom adapter. In order to do that you have to declare your own class this way:
public class MyCustomAdapter extends SimpleAdapter
give it a try.